# How can I put a piece of text on top of my google chart?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I wish to have text in the middle of my chart, and also update it if possible. does anyone know how to do this?

I'm already trying annotations, but I cannot make it appear

Comment: What have you tried? ref: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart
FWIW Feels like you could layer the chart behind other elements using a variety of techniques.

Comment: Please put what code you have tried in your question so we may best help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accomplish this using [an overlay as documented here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays).

You have a lot of interactivity options open to you, using various combinations of css and js.

I've provided a simple example that accomplishes what you asked for.  The text can be updated purely with javascript, as demonstrated.

The documentation provides more sophisticated examples should you need or desire placement calculations based on attributes or elements within the chart.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004',  1000,      400],
    ['2005',  1170,      460],
    ['2006',  660,       1120],
    ['2007',  1030,      540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function overlayUpdate() {
    let overlayDiv = document.getElementById('overlay');
    overlayDiv.innerHTML = '<div>Text updated</div>';
}
```

```css
#chart {
    position: relative;
}
#curve_chart {
    width: 900px; 
    height: 500px;   
}
.overlay-text {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family:'Arial Black'; 
    font-size: 60px;
    top: 100px;   /* chartArea top  */
    left: 400px; /* chartArea left */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
    <div id="curve_chart"></div>
    <div id="overlay" class="overlay-text">
        <div>Your Text Here</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <button id="update" onclick="overlayUpdate();">Update Overlay</button>
 </div>
```